# iOS how to expand Image View to borders in Launch Screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I am 2 days into iOS app development, I am quite new. The very first thing I wanted to implement in my app is a Launch Screen using `Storyboards` (I heard there are other ways but I found this the easier). I have a vector-based PDF file (image) because I wanted to implement a gradient background without a loss in quality that supports all device resolutions.

I created an Image View in the Interface-Builder (IB) but it does not automatically stretch vertically and horizontally to fill the device length.

- I simulate my results on an iPhone 14, only thin white margins appear, but on a large iPad, the majority of the screen is white. It's like as if the the image resolution is fixed across all devices.

No matter what resizing I try, I can't get it to work.

I come from an Android app development background so something like this is very easy to implement (we have `fill_parent` / `match_parent` to stress the view to its containing parent view dimensions). Is such a behavior possible on iOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply constraint on the image in launch screen.
[image]

Comment: It's working now. I didn't know what those arrows do until now. Btw, what's the difference between `Launch Screen.xib` and `Launch Screen.storyboard` ? And are both formats used now ? Do they only have something to do with Launch screen ? I am focused only on iOS Swift programming (SwiftUI etc)

Comment: Technically, Storyboard files and XIB files both her interface builders. `Launch Screen.xib` was used in previous version of Xcode and in the newer version of Xcode it create `Launch Screen.storyboard`. We can use as per our need.